# I am new to mysql.. how can i do this in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
----------------
 category | c_id
----------------
  A       |  1

  B       |  2

  C       |  3
----------------
```

Table 2

```
---------------------
 name     | c_value
---------------------
  A       |  
  A       |  
  B       |  
  B       | 
---------------------
```

Hi, I want an output like below from the above two tables..

Output

```
---------------------
 name     | c_value
---------------------
  A       |  1

  A       |  1

  B       |  2

  B       |  2
---------------------
```

I have more than 200 category like these.. is there any way i can do this in mysql??

Sorry for my mistake... i was little unclear in my question.. i need to update the table2.. not just select query and show table..

Comment: Your requirement is unclear to me.  The examples you gave strip out all the meaning.  I'd recommend learning SQL, paying particular attention to JOIN and GROUP BY.

Comment: You want to update the `c_value` column of `table2` or just show the output in select query??

Comment: i want to update it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table2 as t2
inner join table1 as t1 on t1.category=t2.name
set t2.c_value = t1.c_id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/342533/1)